# Why is PHP saying my class name is already being used when It's the first time I've declared it

Tags: php

Apologies for the long code, it's 4 files but I have no choice since the problem can be any where. Thankfully I've found the solution I'm just trying to figure out why this had happened in the first place, so that will probably cut down the time significantly.

**classes/Cart.php**

```
<?php

require './classes/CartItem.php';




class Cart
{

    var int $id;
    var array $listoforderitem = [];



    function addProduct($productt, $quantityy)
    {

        if ($productt->stock < $quantityy) {

            print("We don't have that many stock !");
        } else {

            $productt->stock -= $quantityy;

            $newcartitem = new CartItem($productt, $quantityy);


            array_push($this->listoforderitem, $newcartitem);

            // var_dump(count(($this->listoforderitem)));


            return $newcartitem;
        }
    }

    function getTotalQuantity()
    {

        $quantityy = 0;

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->listoforderitem); $i++) {

            $quantityy += $this->listoforderitem[$i]->quantity;

            // var_dump($quantityy);
        }

        return $quantityy;
    }

    function getTotalSum()
    {

        $sum = 0;

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->listoforderitem); $i++) {

            $orderitemsum = $this->listoforderitem[$i]->quantity * $this->listoforderitem[$i]->product->price;

            $sum += $orderitemsum;

            // var_dump($sum);
        }

        // var_dump(0 < count($this->listoforderitem));

        return $sum;
    }
}
```

**classes/CartItem.php**

```
<?php


class CartItem
{
    var object $product;
    var int $quantity;


    function __construct(object $product, int $quantity)
    {


        $this->product = $product;
        $this->quantity = $quantity;
    }


    function increaseQuantity(): void
    {

        if ($this->product->stock < 1) {
            print("We don't have that many stock !");
        } else {

            $this->product->stock -= 1;

            $this->quantity += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

**classes/Product.php**

```
    <?php


require_once './classes/CartItem.php';


class Product
{

    var int $id;
    var string $name;
    var int $price;
    var int $stock;


    function __construct(int $id, string $name, int $price, int $stock)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->price = $price;
        $this->stock = $stock;
    }

    function addToCart($cart, $quantityy)
    {

        if ($quantityy > $this->stock) {

            print("We don't have that many stock !");
        } else {

            $this->stock -= $quantityy;

            $newcartitem = new CartItem($this, $quantityy);



            array_push($cart->listoforderitem, $newcartitem);

            // var_dump(count($cart->listoforderitem));

            return $newcartitem;
        }
    }
}
```

**./index.php**

```
require_once './classes/Product.php';
require_once './classes/Cart.php';


$product1 = new Product(1, "iPhone 11", 2500, 10);
$product2 = new Product(2, "M2 SSD", 400, 10);
$product3 = new Product(3, "Samsung Galaxy S20", 3200, 10);
$cart = new Cart();
$cartItem1 = $cart->addProduct($product1, 1);
$cartItem2 = $product2->addToCart($cart, 1);
echo "Number of items in cart: " . PHP_EOL;
echo $cart->getTotalQuantity() . PHP_EOL; // This must print 2
echo "Total price of items in cart: " . PHP_EOL;
echo $cart->getTotalSum() . PHP_EOL; // This must print 2900

$cartItem2->increaseQuantity();
$cartItem2->increaseQuantity();

echo "Number of items in cart: " . PHP_EOL;
echo $cart->getTotalQuantity() . PHP_EOL; // This must print 4

echo "Total price of items in cart: " . PHP_EOL;
echo $cart->getTotalSum() . PHP_EOL; // This must print 3700


echo "Number of items in cart: " . PHP_EOL;
echo $cart->getTotalQuantity() . PHP_EOL; // This must print 4

echo "Total price of items in cart: " . PHP_EOL;
echo $cart->getTotalSum() . PHP_EOL; // This must print 3700
```

So if I were to run the code on index.html it gave me this error

```
Fatal error: Cannot declare class CartItem, because the name is already in use in C:\coding\apps\xampp\htdocs\oop_cart_logic\classes\CartItem.php on line 4
```

which is weird because I've never declared it anywhere else.

now the solution for this it to shuffle the `required_once` from this:

```
require_once './classes/Product.php';
require_once './classes/Cart.php';
```

to this:

```
require_once './classes/Cart.php';
require_once './classes/Product.php';
```

and it worked perfectly! any idea of why this had happened?

Comment: in `Product.php` you're referencing `new CartItem($this, $quantityy)`, but you haven't required it in that file, so it hasn't necessarily loaded yet. So loading `Cart.php` before `Product.php` fixes it in index.php, but you should really add `require_once Cart.php` in `Product.php` to fix the root issue. That doesn't totally align with the error you got, but changing your `require` to `require_once` in `Cart.php` should help with that too.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones I just forgot to highlight the whole file. Thank you for the feedback I've edited the question accordingly!

Comment: You also should have a look at [autoloading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php), [spl_autoload_register](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.spl-autoload-register.php) and eventually [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) that does all that _magic_ for you

Comment: There is no requirement to have `Cart` or `CartItem` loaded before `Product` is defined. The order that you put your require statements is irrelevant here and the code that you've posted works just fine in both cases. Your error is caused by something not posted here. You are likely running some code in addition to index.php, perhaps via somebody else's autoloader. In any case, take the advice of @Zyigh -- get rid of all require statements and use an SPL-4 autoloader yourself, and this type of issue just goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was caused by me using `require` instead of `require_once` in `Cart` so if class `Product` comes first then the class `CartItem` will be redeclared since class `Cart` did not check if `CartItem` was already declared in the code.